# JSTL 1.0 String Functions

Tags: string, function, jstl

I am trying to use some string functions like trim or `concat` using JSTL. I tried the following.

I tried adding `<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>` but I ended up with the error. I think this is for other JSTL version like 1.2 or 1.1

All I would need to know is how to use string function in JSTL 1.0

Comment: You should really tell *what* was the error. Which server are you using (Glassfish, Tomcat 6/7, . .)? What is your jstl implementation?

Comment: The function library is not available for JSTL 1.0. You have to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

JSTL 1.0 does not have the `/jsp` part in the taglib URI. Remove that part.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/functions" %>
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, [JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) does *not* have `trim()` and `concat()`. You'd still need to look for a different solution to your concrete problem. For example, a custom EL function.

Comment: I added as per your suggestion but I get the error "The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/functions cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application" in the log. Any suggestions. My Web.XML file has the following  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>
      core
    </taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/tlds/coreTaglib1_0.tld
    </taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>
      dsp
    </taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/tlds/dspjspTaglib1_0.tld
    </taglib-location>
  </taglib>

Comment: Then you didn't have installed JSTL in your webapp at all. Please don't ignore the link to our JSTL tag wiki page.

Comment: We are using JSTL in our webapp almost in all the pages. I have the following libs files and tld and in the webapp WEB-INF folder under lib and tlds.

Under LIB:

coreTaglib1_0.jar
dspjspTaglib1_0.jar
jaxen-full.jar
jstl.jar
saxpath.jar
standard.jar
taglibs-log.jar 

Under TLDS:

 c-rt.tld
 c.tld
 coreTaglib1_0.tld
 dspjspELTaglib1_0.tld
 dspjspTaglib1_0.tld
 fmt-rt.tld
 fmt.tld

Please advise

Comment: Doesn't work for me either! ``core`` and ``sql`` works, though.